# Special case of inequality for negative numbers

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.
Given
$$|(x_1-y_1)\cdot(x_2-y_2)|=|x_1x_2-x_1y_2-x_2y_1+y_1y_2| \geq |x_1x_2-y_1y_2|$$

I know that this inequality is true as long as $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \geq 0$.

---

My question is the following: Is the inequality still true if we take $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. not only for non-negative numbers?

Comment: Can you include a proof of the inequality, and point out where positivity is used?

Comment: Take $x_1 > y_1 > 0$ and $x_2> 0  > y_2$, and you should be able to find numerous counter examples.  EG $ x_ 1  = 2,  y _1 = 1$.